# Dynamic PictureBox Creation and Attach To TabControl

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am trying to create dynamic `PictureBoxes` from database for multiple image display and finally attach these images in a `TabControl`. I tried something as follows that throws an exception - **Object not found**:

```vb
    For Each dr In dbdataset.Rows
        Dim pics As PictureBox() = New PictureBox(2) {}
        Dim imgBytes As Byte() = CType(dr("image"), Byte()) 'Image in blob

        Dim tc As TypeConverter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(GetType(Bitmap))
        Dim MyBitmap As Bitmap = CType(tc.ConvertFrom(imgBytes), Bitmap)

        For i As Integer = 0 To dbdataset.Rows.Count 'Getting the exception here
            pics(i).Image = MyBitmap
            TabPage1.Controls.Add(pics(i))
        Next
    Next
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Anything that I missed here though I declared the `PictureBox` object creation at the beginning?

**Sample**:

[image: Image Gallery]

Comment: Two nested for loops on rows of a single table?

Comment: The name of this variable gives me pause. `dbdataset.Rows` If this is a DataSet then there is no .Rows property but the code wouldn't run at all. I am assuming that this is a DataTable.

Comment: If `dbdataset` is actually a DataTable, you can write `For each dr As DataRow in dbdataset.Rows dim pic As PictureBox = new PictureBox() pic.Image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(CType(dr("image"), Byte()))) TabPage1.Controls.Add(pic) Next`

Comment: You are creating a new array with each iteration of the outer loop.

Comment: Since you hard coded the size of your array but not the upper number of the inner loop you are begging for an "index out of range" error.

Comment: This is the sort of code you end up with when you start writing it without knowing what it has to do. I don't mean that you don't know the final result you want but rather the steps to get there. What is the actual algorithm, i.e. the specific set of steps, that that code is supposed to be implementing? If you don't know that then you shouldn't be writing any code yet. If you do know that, I'm not sure how you could end up with code that clearly doesn't do something useful.

Comment: Also, you ought to add a `TableLayoutPanel` or `FlowLayoutPanel` to the `TabPage` and then add the `PictureBoxes` to that. That will automatically handle the layout for you because, as it stands, if you were actually creating any `PictureBoxes`, they would all be on top of each other.

Comment: @Jimi I don't think that `dbdataset(0)` would work for `DataSet`. It would need to be `dbdataset.Tables(0)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used `List(Of T)` so I didn't have to worry about the size of an array. I made 2 lists, one for the picture boxes and one for the bitmaps.

I also added a `FlowLayoutPanel` to the tab page so, I wouldn't have to worry about positioning the picture boxes.

Finally, I looped through the picture boxes adding the `.Image` from the bitmap list. Lastly, increment the index on each iteration.

These lines

```
        Dim imgBytes As Byte() = DirectCast(dr("image"), Byte()) 'Image in blob
        Dim tc As TypeConverter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(GetType(Bitmap))
        Dim MyBitmap = CType(tc.ConvertFrom(imgBytes), Bitmap)
```

I didn't check except to change to DirectCast which I think is faster (skips some checking code). I am assuming you know way more about graphics than I do.

```
Private Sub OPCode()
    Dim pics As New List(Of PictureBox)
    For index = 0 To dbdataset.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim pic As New PictureBox
        pic.Name = "PB" & index.ToString

        pics.Add(pic)
    Next
    Dim Bitmaps As New List(Of Bitmap)
    For Each dr As DataRow In dbdataset.Rows
        Dim imgBytes As Byte() = DirectCast(dr("image"), Byte()) 'Image in blob
        Dim tc As TypeConverter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(GetType(Bitmap))
        Dim MyBitmap = CType(tc.ConvertFrom(imgBytes), Bitmap)
        Bitmaps.Add(MyBitmap)
    Next
    Dim i As Integer
    For Each picBox In pics 'Getting the exception here
        picBox.Image = Bitmaps(i)
        FlowLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(picBox)
        i += 1
    Next
End Sub
```